# How to interpolate colours to double its number in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, color-palette

I have a list of 9 colors like this:

```
  colors = [
           [0, 82, 246, 255],
           [0, 196, 196, 255],
           [0, 137, 83, 255],
           [1, 233, 11, 255],
           [234, 255, 31, 255],
           [255, 176, 0, 255],
           [247, 19, 0, 255],
           [193, 0, 76, 255],
           [255, 0, 255, 255]]
```

I want to use matplotlib to double the number of colours with interpolated ones. I have used `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` without success:

```
  cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('test', np.array(colors) / 255, 
                                         N=len(colors))
  
  colors = cm(np.linspace(0, 1, 2 * len(colors)))
  colors = (colors * 255).astype('uint8')
```

However I get the same colours but repeated:

```
array([[  0,  82, 246, 255],
       [  0,  82, 246, 255],
       [  0, 196, 196, 255],
       [  0, 196, 196, 255],
       [  0, 137,  83, 255],
       [  0, 137,  83, 255],
       [  1, 233,  11, 255],
       [  1, 233,  11, 255],
       [234, 255,  31, 255],
       [234, 255,  31, 255],
       [255, 176,   0, 255],
       [255, 176,   0, 255],
       [247,  18,   0, 255],
       [247,  18,   0, 255],
       [193,   0,  76, 255],
       [193,   0,  76, 255],
       [255,   0, 255, 255],
       [255,   0, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

How can I get the expected behaviour, with the colours I originally I had, plus others in the middle?

Comment: Do you look for "numerical in the middle" or do you want colors that actually look as if you transitioned them from red to yellow (get orange between) - if the latter the RGB Model is ill suited for that task, you might want to look for a HSL representation first.

Comment: In principle I'm fine with the RGB model. My question is more in the line: is `LinearSegmentedColormap` working as supposed to here?

Comment: try `N=len(colors)*2` as param to `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` and print the resulting cm - from the doc I would presume it is already interpolated to double the amount of values. Not sure, haven't used that one. Selfanswer if it fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "expected" behavior isn't possible: if you have 9 colors, and you take 18 equally spaced interpolated values, only the first and the last value will come from your initial set. To have your initial set as part of the list, you need a multiple minus one.

The input to `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()` can't be rgb values in the range 0-255: they need to be float values in the range 0-1. Also, the `N=` parameter will be the number of internally stored values. If you set `N` equal to the original number of colors, no interpolated colors will be calculated. For most flexibility you can set N to 256.

Afterwards, you can multiply the values again by 255 to get rgb values in the range 0-255.

```py
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = [[0, 82, 246, 255],
          [0, 196, 196, 255],
          [0, 137, 83, 255],
          [1, 233, 11, 255],
          [234, 255, 31, 255],
          [255, 176, 0, 255],
          [247, 19, 0, 255],
          [193, 0, 76, 255],
          [255, 0, 255, 255]]

cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', np.array(colors) / 255, 256)
colors_18 = (cm(np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors) * 2)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
colors_17 = (cm(np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors) * 2 - 1)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

colors_18:

```
array([[  0,  82, 246, 255],
       [  0, 135, 222, 255],
       [  0, 189, 198, 255],
       [  0, 171, 149, 255],
       [  0, 143,  96, 255],
       [  0, 170,  57, 255],
       [  0, 216,  23, 255],
       [ 69, 239,  16, 255],
       [179, 249,  26, 255],
       [238, 236,  23, 255],
       [248, 199,   9, 255],
       [253, 148,   0, 255],
       [249,  74,   0, 255],
       [240,  16,   8, 255],
       [215,   7,  44, 255],
       [196,   0,  86, 255],
       [225,   0, 170, 255],
       [255,   0, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

colors_17:

```
array([[  0,  82, 246, 255],
       [  0, 139, 220, 255],
       [  0, 195, 195, 255],
       [  0, 166, 138, 255],
       [  0, 137,  82, 255],
       [  0, 185,  46, 255],
       [  3, 233,  11, 255],
       [120, 244,  21, 255],
       [234, 253,  30, 255],
       [244, 214,  14, 255],
       [254, 172,   0, 255],
       [250,  94,   0, 255],
       [245,  18,   1, 255],
       [218,   9,  39, 255],
       [194,   0,  80, 255],
       [225,   0, 170, 255],
       [255,   0, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

To use colors in other applications, matplotlib also provides a `to_hex` function (which doesn't work on arrays, only on individual colors):

```py
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
colors_18_hex = [to_hex(cm(v)) for v in np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors) * 2)]
# ['#0052f6', '#0088de', '#00bdc7', '#00ac95', '#009060', '#00ab3a', '#01d818', '#46ef11', '#b3fa1a', '#efec18', '#f9c709', '#fe9400', '#fa4a00', '#f11109', '#d7082d', '#c50057', '#e200ab', '#ff00ff']"
```

Here is a plot to show how the interpolation goes on:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

colors = np.array([[0, 82, 246, 255], [0, 196, 196, 255], [0, 137, 83, 255], [1, 233, 11, 255], [234, 255, 31, 255], [255, 176, 0, 255], [247, 19, 0, 255], [193, 0, 76, 255], [255, 0, 255, 255]])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(15, 5))

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors / 255, len(colors))),
             ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors)), orientation='horizontal', cax=axs[0])
axs[0].set_title("9 colors, no interpolation")

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors / 255, 256)),
             ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors) * 2 - 1), orientation='horizontal', cax=axs[1])
axs[1].set_title("positions of 17 colors")
axs[1].xaxis.grid(True, ls='--')

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors / 255, 256)),
             ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, len(colors) * 2), orientation='horizontal', cax=axs[2])
axs[2].set_title("positions of 18 colors")
axs[2].xaxis.grid(True, ls='--')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: linear segmented colormap from list]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar but maybe easier.

I have this numpy array `colvals`:

```py
array([[0.90588235, 0.96078431, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.81568627, 0.92156863, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.64705882, 0.84705882, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.45490196, 0.75294118, 0.98823529, 1.        ],
       [0.30196078, 0.67058824, 0.96862745, 1.        ],
       [0.2       , 0.60392157, 0.94117647, 1.        ],
       [0.13333333, 0.54509804, 0.90196078, 1.        ],
       [0.10980392, 0.49411765, 0.83921569, 1.        ],
       [0.09803922, 0.44313725, 0.76078431, 1.        ],
       [0.09411765, 0.39215686, 0.67058824, 1.        ]])
```

It is in rgba format.

Transforming in into colormap looks like:

```py
cmp_blue = ListedColormap(colvals)
cmp_blue
```

[image]

Now I make it more granular

```py
inbetween_color_amount = 10

# the 10 is from the original 10 colors, the 4 is for R, G, B, A
newcolvals = np.zeros(shape=(10 * (inbetween_color_amount) - (inbetween_color_amount - 1), 4))

# add first one already
newcolvals[0] = colvals[0]

for i, (rgba1, rgba2) in enumerate(zip(colvals[:-1], np.roll(colvals, -1, axis=0)[:-1])):
    for j, (p1, p2) in enumerate(zip(rgba1, rgba2)):
        flow = np.linspace(p1, p2, (inbetween_color_amount + 1))
        # discard first 1 since we already have it from previous iteration
        flow = flow[1:]
        newcolvals[ i * (inbetween_color_amount) + 1 : (i + 1) * (inbetween_color_amount) + 1, j] = flow
    
newcolvals
```

This time:

```py
cmp_blue = ListedColormap(newcolvals)
cmp_blue
```

I get:

[image]